# What does the number after the field name mean in this mysql index?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

We're looking at the indexes of a few tables in mySQL and noticed something. There are several indexes that contain the `type` field, but some of them have a number in parentheses after the field name, while others don't.

[image]

For example, the index for keyname `node_status_type` includes `type` in the list of fields, but there is no number. `node_title_type`, on the other hand, includes `type (4)`. What does the `(4)` mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means it is indexing the first `(X)` number of characters/bytes in the field.

It is actually good practice to use column index prefixes in any cases where the data will be unique (or distinguishable for your purposes) within the first X characters/bytes. It keeps index sizes down.

Check the documentation for more information with regards to prefix index usage on different field data types.

[The Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html)

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure what it was called, so didn't know where to look in the documentation.